# FOC and Inverter modulation techniques

Tags: inverter, modulation

I'm not sure I understand how FOC and modulation techniques work together. If I understand properly, the output of the FOC algorithm is the required voltage at each phase of the motor that is given with respect to the neutral point of the motor. However, the voltage that is affected by the inverter is the "pole voltage" (with respect to the neutral point of the DC bus). Is that right? Does that mean that the required voltages aren't controlled directly?

Also, the required voltages can be both positive and negative, but the DC bus is only positive, how does that work?

EDIT:
Thanks for the answers but I need a numerical example.
Lets assume I'm using SPWM and the output of my FOC algorithm is \$ (V_{dc}/2, -V_{dc}/4, -V_{dc}/4)\$. As far as I understand, in case of SPWM I need duty cycles of (1, 1/4, 1/4) to generate these voltages. On the other hand, the voltages are generated with respect to the neutral of the dc bus and hence are pole voltages, but what I need is the phase voltages. How are these pole voltages converted into the correct phase voltages?

Comment: Have a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_control_(motor)   Applications §8 and picture by side. And also to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_transformation

Comment: And here a more complete example notice http://www.zilog.com/docs/appnotes/AN0378.pdf or this https://www.ti.com/lit/an/spra494/spra494.pdf?ts=1639926312848&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.be%252F

Answer (score 4):

FOC and Modulation techniques are two separate but important concepts associated with motor control or wider 3phase control. One provides means to control a quantity while the other stimulates the load.

**Field Oriented Control**

This is a method where via Clarke & Park transformations, 3phase sinusiodal quantities that are 120° separated (typically current) are manipulated to produce two DC quantities.

[image]

Imagine you want to control the load current to a certain level, it is easier to control to a DC value and use a classic PI controller rather than deal with 3 independent sinusiodal waveforms. Using Clark&Park to produce to DC terms (in the rotating frame of reference) from 3phase (in the abc time variant frame of reference) is extremely convenient for active rectifiers, inverters, motor-drives.

When Id and Iq (derived from Iabc) are controlled and the load is an electric machine, this is referred to as Field Oriented Control as Id and Iq relate to the direct and quadrature flux components of a load motor.

**modulation techniques**

One you have generated a Vd and Vq demands that the controller "thinks" is required to remove the current error, these are converted to Vabc demands via inverse Clark and Park transformations.  This is the voltage that must be applied to the motor. But how? via modulation. The two main methods are

1. Sinusoidal modulation
2. Space Vector modulation

[image]

Sinusoidal modulation is easier as it treats each sinusoidal voltage demand independently and compares against a suitable triangle wave to produce the modulation signals. The downside is the "bus utilisation" is lower

Space Vector treats the entire bridge as a whole and aims to generate all 3 waveforms concurrently. The benefit is increased bus utilisation.

Why is the voltage +- about the neutral? because for a star-wound machine, you will "drag" the phase to the +DC and then down to the -DC and this action produces a "common-mode" with respect to earth, but differentially it is now swinging +- around the mod point of the DClink

[image]
[image]

and the associated SVPWM waveforms:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y17bE.png]